# The review page keeps to show the questions/answers of the day

Tags: support, review-page

All times I visit the review page [here on meta](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/review) or on [the main site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review), the page shows the answers/questions of the day, instead of remembering the last tab I selected (e.g. "week").

Is this done intentionally, or should the review page remember which tab I selected the last time, in the same way it remembers the tab I selected in /questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page makes a decision about which time interval to show based on *question volume*.

It is not a sticky tab in this case.